# Poblate objects from csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, object, populate

I've got a csv file `paises.csv` that looks like this:

```
Chile;17000000;0.72;FALSE;0
Hanslandia;2000000;0.2;FALSE;91
Bastiland;4000000;0;TRUE;0
```

The first column is the `country` name, and the following are some features of it, such as its population. So, I created a `country` class and tried to create countries and populate it with its features from the csv file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##Importing libraries
import csv
##Defining classes
class country:
    def __init__(self,inhabitants,tolerance,underground,infected_perc):
        self.inhabitants = inhabitants
        self.tolerance = tolerance
        self.underground = underground
        self.infected_perc = infected_perc

with open('paises.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ";")
    for row in reader:
        row[0]=country(row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4])
```

The code runs. However, it doesn't even create the countries. When I try to see a `row`, what I get is this:

```
AttributeError("Can't get attribute 'country' on ",)
```

Comment: where are you planning to store your data?

Comment: well, in objects of the class "country". the first row'll be the name, and the following will be its features

Comment: you need a container (list, dictionary, set) in order to store your countries. Otherwise, it seems you are missing some concept of classes.

Comment: `row[0]=country(row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4])` creates a `country` instance, copies it to the first slot in `rows`, overwriting the country name. And then it gets thrown away when you read the next row. I don't think you want to do that. As lmiguelvargasf said, you should be saving that stuff into some container, eg a dictionary, with `row[0]` as the key and the  `country` instance as the value.

Comment: Hey! I've just created a dictionary whose key is the country name, and whose value is the object. But, I can't get them. When I try to get dictionary[country], I get the same error: AttributeError("Can't get attribute 'country' on ",)

Comment: @idmdvan, in that case you should probably redefine your class, adding a field for the country name, and using the list you are mentioning. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a container where you can store the countries you are creating. I will also consider capitalizing the name of the class:

```
import csv

class Country:
    def __init__(self,inhabitants,tolerance,underground,infected_perc):
        self.inhabitants = inhabitants
        self.tolerance = tolerance
        self.underground = underground
        self.infected_perc = infected_perc

countries = {}
with open('paises.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ";")
   for row in reader:
       countries[row[0]] = Country(row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
```

Your countries you want are store in the dictionary `countries` and you can access them with its name as key. For example, to access Chile you can use `countries['Chile']`.

**Update:**

In case you want to use a list instead of a dictionary you should add a field to your class to store the country name:

```
import csv

class Country:
    def __init__(self,name, inhabitants,tolerance,underground,infected_perc):
        self.name =  name
        self.inhabitants = inhabitants
        self.tolerance = tolerance
        self.underground = underground
        self.infected_perc = infected_perc

countries = []
with open('paises.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ";")
   for row in reader:
       countries.append(Country(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
```

In case of using a list as container, you can substitute `countries.append(Country(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))` by `countries.append(Country(*row))`

Comment: Thank you a lot! However I've got two problems: in Spyder, I can't see the dictionary because I get "AttributeError("Can't get attribute 'Country' on ",)

Comment: The other thing is that I should be able to access the country as an object, not as a dictionary key... how can I change that? Thanks in advance! I was really stuck with this.

Comment: @idmdvan, look my answer using a list, I think that is more appropriate for your case.

Comment: @idmdvan, in case you found useful my answer, please validate it.

Comment: it's perfect! I've just got a question... if I wanna access my country's population, with this list method, I've gotta do countries[index].population. Do you have any ideas of how to access it like country.population, like as an object itself, not a list index? Thanks!

Comment: @idmdvan, try  the second part of my answer, where I use a list instead of a dictionary, so you can use `countries[index].population`. If you are using a dictionary you have no way to use `countries[key].population`.